# Missing information in correlation matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, correlation

I created a correlation matrix using `pandas.DataFrame.corr(method = 'spearman')` and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8z0V.png) result. The column `RAIN` does not contain any correlation between it and the other columns.

My question is - why are the correlations between `RAIN` and the other columns blank?

My dataset contains the following columns with their respective datatypes -

```
PM2.5      float64
PM10       float64
SO2        float64
NO2        float64
CO         float64
O3         float64
TEMP       float64
PRES       float64
DEWP       float64
RAIN       float64
WSPM       float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

First debugging step would be to check with df.isna().all() if RAIN column is all nan (which would be kicked out)

Comment: Not even `NaN`, if it's just a constant it will be null in the correlation matrix

Comment: @rob247 `df.isna().all()` returns `False` for all columns.

Comment: @ALollz I ran `df.nunique()` to check for unique values and `RAIN` returned 253.